# Group array by property name and add count

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have the following data structure:

```
var data = [
   { MainHeader: Header1, SubHeader: 'one'},
   { MainHeader: Header1, SubHeader: 'two'},
   { MainHeader: Header2, SubHeader: 'three'},
   { MainHeader: Header2, SubHeader: 'four'},
   { MainHeader: Header2, SubHeader: 'five'}
];
```

I need to turn it into something like this:

```
var groupheaders = [
  { startColName: 'one', numberofCols: 2, title: Header1},
  { startColName: 'three', numberofCols: 3, title: Header2}
];
```

Is there an elegant way to achieve this with Lodash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a mapping object with each `MainHeader` as a key. Update the key's count if a `MainHeader` is already added. Else, add a new key and an object as its value

Then, use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values as an array:

```js
const data = [{MainHeader:"Header1",SubHeader:"one"},{MainHeader:"Header1",SubHeader:"two"},{MainHeader:"Header2",SubHeader:"three"},{MainHeader:"Header2",SubHeader:"four"},{MainHeader:"Header2",SubHeader:"five"}],
      map = {};

data.forEach(({ MainHeader, SubHeader }) => {
  if(map[MainHeader])
    map[MainHeader].numberofCols++
  else
    map[MainHeader] = { title: MainHeader, startColName: SubHeader, numberofCols: 1 };
})

let output = Object.values(map);

console.log(output)
```

ES5 solution:

```js
var data = [{MainHeader:"Header1",SubHeader:"one"},{MainHeader:"Header1",SubHeader:"two"},{MainHeader:"Header2",SubHeader:"three"},{MainHeader:"Header2",SubHeader:"four"},{MainHeader:"Header2",SubHeader:"five"}],
      map = {};

data.forEach(function(o) {
  if(map[o.MainHeader])
    map[o.MainHeader].numberofCols++
  else
    map[o.MainHeader] = { title: o.MainHeader, startColName: o.SubHeader, numberofCols: 1 };
})

var output = Object.keys(map).map(function(k) {
  return map[k];
});

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thank you, it runs here but I am getting a syntax error "Expected :"...looking into it now and will accept as soon as I can make it work. Thank you so very much for actually answering my very specific question.

Comment: I marked it as accepted but there are two issues with it: forEach(({ MainHeader, SubHeader }) throws an error and Object.values doesn't work in IE. I managed to eliminate the second issue but forEach(({ MainHeader, SubHeader }) I need to rework...any idea how? i am not familar with this syntax and can't find it in the documentation for the forEach

Comment: @sarsnake it's probably because of [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) of the parameter (new ES6 syntax). You can use it without it, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/u0js2pbh/ (`Object.values` is also ES6 BTW)

Comment: Thanks but it still not working on this IE11...which I have to support sadly

Comment: @sarsnake updated the answer with an alternative for ES5 syntax (for IE11). Hopefully I've covered everything (`let` to `var`, arrow functions to `function`, removed destructuring, changed use `Object.keys` to get the values etc)

Comment: Yes thank you so much!!!!!